# Why does CORS block my Http request when sent from the browser but not from the terminal

Tags: javascript, networking, xmlhttprequest, cors, network-security

I am a little confused on the security provided by CORS. Below are two HTTP requests that are practically the same, one works the other does not, one is via curl the other is javascript in the browser.

Terminal

```
$ curl https://www.google.com/
--> Returns a page
```

Browser:

```
// Open the console in the browser (or spin put localhost)
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.google.com");
xhr.send();
--> CORS Error
```

Try again:

```
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "https://www.google.com");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS');
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,Authorization,Content-Type,X-Auth-Token');
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", 'true') 
  
  xhr.send();
--> CORS Error still
```

So I am guessing the google.com server has it set to only accept requests from the google domain. But when I curl from my terminal that isn't part of the google domain I get a 200 response with HTML, ect.

**So why would the server respond to my terminal with no domain, but doesn't respond when I use javascript in the browser?**

Thanks ^.^

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) _"Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer"_ A quick search for "CORS" with my search engine gave me the answer in the first paragraph of the first result.

Answer (score 3):

CORS is a security feature that in the end is implemented by your browser. Which is why you would never see CORS errors when curling from a terminal. See also: [this post from mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

which says:

> Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS (en-US)) is a mechanism that uses additional HTTP headers to tell a browser to let a web application running at one origin (domain) have permission to access selected resources from a server at a different origin.

Answer (score -1):

CORS is a feature provided by the browser.
CORS is a mechanism which aims to allow requests made on behalf of you and at the same time block some requests made by rogue JS and is triggered whenever you are making an HTTP request to:

1. a different domain (eg. site at example.com calls api.com)
2. a different sub domain (eg. site at example.com calls api.example.com)
3. a different port (eg. site at example.com calls example.com:3001)
4. a different protocol (eg. site at https://example.com calls http://example.com)

Please find the attached article - https://medium.com/@baphemot/understanding-cors-18ad6b478e2b